# Cannot access static files from URL in express application

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, static-files

I have built a basic express app as below -

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello World!" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I want to serve static files directly from the browser URL, and according to [this express doc page](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) it is indeed possible.

Accordingly, I have created a folder called `public` in the root folder and have kept two files in it - one `demo.html`, and one `image.jpg`. My folder structure -

```
express-app
  |- index.js
  |- public
    |- image.jpg
    |- demo.html
```

However, when I try to access `http://localhost:3000/demo.html` or `http://localhost:3000/image.jpg`, I get a `Cannot GET` error.

[image: image.jpg]
[image: demo.html]

Can anybody please tell me why it isn't working?

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `node /path/to/index.js` ?

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/index.html` isn't going to map onto `demo.html`

Comment: Hi Quentin, thank you - I edited the question to rectify my mistake. I am in the root folder (`express-app`) when I run `node /path/to/index.js`.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `node /path/to/index.js`?

Comment: I am in the root folder (`express-app`), where I directly run `node index.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));
> ```

`__dirname` does not include a trailing slash.

`__dirname + "public"` will give you something like: `/home/me/express-apppublic` — a directory that doesn't exist.

The documentation you link to shows the use of `path.join` to include the correct directory separator for your operating system.

> ```
> const path = require('path')
> app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
> ```

Don't omit that part!

Comment: Hi Quentin, thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot to use `path` module. Anyways, now it's working correctly. Much appreciated!